# 404 error when making an ajax call to controller from view in rails for dynamic drop down select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, select, routes

I am trying to dynamically populate a select list and I am getting a 404 error when I make my ajax call to my controller. I have looked around but cannot find out why I am getting this error.

My controller where the method I want to call is.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        #@users = User.all
        myList = [["A",1],["B"],2]
        @classList = myList
        render "index.html.erb"
    end
.  
.
. 
    def changeclasses
        @classlist = [["B",2]]
    end
end
```

And this is my view

```
<%= form_for UnoClass.new do |f| %>
Department: <%= select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select([['Accounting',  'ACCT'], 2),
{ id: 'departSelect'}) %>
<br />
Course : <%= select_tag(:course, options_for_select(@classList)) %>
<br />
Section : <%= f.text_area :section %>
<br />
<%= f.text_area :sessionId, value: request.session_options[:id], style: "display:none;" %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#departSelect').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
               url : "/changeclasses"
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

and my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :uno_classes

  resources :users 
  root :to => 'users#index'
  get '/changeclasses' => "users#changeclasses"
```

This is the error that I grab from the developer tools on chrome.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/changeclasses 404 (Not Found)
```

So, when I make a change to the upper select box departSelect, it makes a call to changeclasses but it cannot find it.

Also when I do rake routes the correct route shows up.

```
 changeclasses GET    /changeclasses(.:format)        users#changeclasses
```

I have not implemented the method yet but it should change the @classList and therefore change the contents of the course select box and it never gets called because of the 404 error.

Any help would be appreciated because I cannot figure out why there is a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas on things you can try to get it working.

First.  Create a view called "changeclasses.js.erb" in your Users views folder which is what Rails will by default look to load unless you tell it otherwise since its a js request.  You can/should also put the js that you want to run with this particular method in that file (changeclasses.js.erb).

Second. Try updating the ajax call's datatype to "script" so that it will be processed by your controller as js.

```
        $.ajax({
           url : "/changeclasses",
           dataType: "script"
        });
```

Third.  If all that doesn't fix it, I would add the below code to your controller to make it sure it is responding to js requests.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
```

Hope one of those helps!